# How to insert Space (_) after comma (,) using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column Note(text)

Eg- New Delhi,Mumbai,Bangalore

How to find where there is a no space after comma and insert a space after comma using SQL query.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: What's your code so far?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `replace()` function.  If you want to update the data:

```
update table t
    set note = replace(note, ',', ', ')
    where note like '%,%';
```

If you have spaces after comma and these are the *only* spaces, then remove them first:

```
update table t
    set note = replace(replace(note, ' ', ''), ',', ', ')
    where note like '%,%';
```

If you have spaces, some after commas, then the following will work assuming there are no multiple spaces:

```
update table t
    set note = replace(replace(note, ', ', ','), ',', ', ')
    where note like '%,%';
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but you could replace `,_` with `,`, and then `,` with `,_`:

```
select replace(replace('New Delhi, Mumbai,Bangalore', ', ',','), ',', ', ')
-->
New Delhi, Mumbai, Bangalore
```