# SQL (Maria DB) split string separated by comma to rows

Tags: sql, string, csv, mariadb, recursive-query

I have this column:

```
names
John, Mary
Joseph
Eleanor, Sophia, Dani
```

And I want this output:

```
names
John
Mary
Joseph
Eleanor
Sophia
Dani
```

And it should include the SUBSTRING_INDEX function

Comment: This is not a portal to post your questions and get the answers. You have to post what you have tried and our community members would help you correct your mistakes. This is not a go-to place to get answers without trying anything by yourself.

Comment: "A portal to post your questions and get the answers" is literally what stack overflow is.  In fact the arrogance shown in comments such as the one above is what keeps the user base from growing more quickly.

Comment: @MichaelCurrie: Is it **really** one of the goals of stackoverflow.com to make the user base grow more quickly ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select '            ' as name, concat(names, ',') as names, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select substring_index(names, ',', 1),
             substr(names, instr(names, ',') + 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where names like '%,%'
     )
select name
from cte
where lev > 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=38ff6ba97b7edef272140087b68e2395) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: If the cell in the above table were 'John,Mary' (**without a space before 'Mary'**) instead of 'John, Mary', how would the SQL need to be adjusted to handle that? E.g. [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7iVmXN_V) I only get 'aria' instead of 'Maria'.

Comment: One idea would be plugging in your answer from [How to insert Space (_) after comma (,) using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645985/how-to-insert-space-after-comma-using-sql) to make it work...

Comment: Indeed: **[this](https://dbfiddle.uk/NvCjfHYX) now works** (returning 'Maria' correctly instead of the cut-off 'aria').

Comment: This doesn't work. I keep getting `Data too long for column 'name' at row 10`.

Answer (score 3):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
 with recursive
    data as (select concat(names, ', ') names from mytable),
    cte as (
        select 
            substring(names, 1, locate(', ', names) - 1) word,
            substring(names, locate(', ', names) + 2) names
        from data
        union all
        select 
            substring(names, 1, locate(', ', names) - 1) word,
            substring(names, locate(', ', names) + 2) names
        from cte
        where locate(', ', names) > 0
    )
select word from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=a2ab624ef70f9791c11d4bc9440dbfb7)**:

```
| word    |
| :------ |
| John    |
| Joseph  |
| Eleanor |
| Mary    |
| Sophia  |
| Dani    |
```

Comment: If the cell in the above table were 'John,Mary' (**without a space before 'Mary'**) instead of 'John, Mary', how would the SQL need to be adjusted to handle that? E.g. [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/35Dr8O60) I only get 'aria' instead of 'Maria'.

Comment: One approach (perhaps not the most elegant) would be the equivalent of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454071/sql-maria-db-split-string-separated-by-comma-to-rows#comment137497075_64454134

Answer (score 3):

Using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```sql
SELECT 
  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names,',',x.x),',',-1)) as name
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 as x union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4) x
WHERE x.x <= LENGTH(names)-LENGTH(REPLACE(names,',',''))+1
```

A (short) explanation:

The function `SUBSTRING_INDEX(names,',',2)` will return the first two names in the string `names`. When using -1 for the last parameter, you will only get the  last element of this string, so you will end up with the second name in names.

The `CROSS JOIN` in this simple example limits the number of names to 4 per record. When you need more names, this should be expanded or a reference to a table with just integers can be used.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/NS9oLm8t)

Comment: Nice and compact solution. 
I don't get why you use ```x.x```. A simple ```x``` would work too.

Comment: When the table `mytable` also has a field named `x` (which is possible) then `x.x` is needed to pick the correct field.

Comment: Unlike the other answers (by [GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb) and [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)), this one also works for cases **without spaces** (e.g., also for 'Jonny,Maria'). :-)

Answer (score 0):

A slight extension of [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64454134/2153622), combining his [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645985/how-to-insert-space-after-comma-using-sql), to cover also cases where there's **no space after the comma** in the original table:

https://dbfiddle.uk/shW05gvo

```
with recursive names_cleaned as (
    select replace(replace(names, ', ', ','), ',', ', ') nc
    from t),
cte as (
      select '            ' as name, concat(nc, ',') as nc, 1 as lev
      from names_cleaned
      union all
      select substring_index(nc, ',', 1),
             substr(nc, instr(nc, ',') + 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where nc like '%,%'
     )
select name
from cte
where lev > 1;
```

---

Also worth noting: [how to combine recursive CTE and normal CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784513/how-to-combine-recursive-cte-and-normal-cte)

---

To easily understand the logic of the recursive CTE, see https://dbfiddle.uk/LbW7LcfD (returning **all columns** and **all rows** of the cte):

```
with recursive cte as (
      select '            ' as name, concat(names, ',') as names, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select substring_index(names, ',', 1),
             substr(names, instr(names, ',') + 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where names like '%,%'
     )
select * -- name
from cte
-- where lev > 1
```

giving

```
+---------+------------------------+-----+
|  name   |         names          | lev |
+---------+------------------------+-----+
|         | John, Mary,            |   1 |
|         | Joseph,                |   1 |
|         | Eleanor, Sophia, Dani, |   1 |
+---------+------------------------+-----+
| John    | Mary,                  |   2 |
| Joseph  |                        |   2 |
| Eleanor | Sophia, Dani,          |   2 |
+---------+------------------------+-----+
| Mary    |                        |   3 |
| Sophia  | Dani,                  |   3 |
+---------+------------------------+-----+
| Dani    |                        |   4 |
+---------+------------------------+-----+
```

of which all but the **non-empty rows of the first column** is discarded.

Answer (score -1):

A little bit tweaked version of above answers:

```
create or replace procedure splitstring(
    value TEXT,
    delim VARCHAR(12)
)
BEGIN 
    with recursive
    data as (select CONCAT(value,delim) as entries),
    cte as (
        select
            substring(entries, 1, locate(delim, entries) - LENGTH(delim)) entry,
            substring(entries, locate(delim, entries) + LENGTH(delim)) entries
        from data
        union all
        select 
            substring(entries, 1, locate(delim, entries) - LENGTH(delim)) entry,
            substring(entries, locate(delim, entries) + LENGTH(delim)) entries
        from cte
        where locate(delim, entries) > 0
    )
select entry from cte where length(entry) > 0;
END
```

Usage

```
call splitrec('Alex,Stitch,Cain,Denton', ',')
```

- Gives a nicely readable and usable table.
- Handles empty strings, string without delimeter present, and nulls.
- Can take in any `delimeter` (of 12 chars length max, which can be tweaked if needed).
- Does not respect whitespaces in the string, which can be ammended by

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(very_messy_string_value, ' ', ''), '\t', ''), '\n', '');
```