# Need to PIVOT 1 table in 4 JOINS

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, pivot

So, this is a verry specific Problem i hope u guys understand what i want to do there:

(MariaDB)

my tables:

**table_toteach:**

| teach-id | teach | teacher | .... | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | Subj1- | Tname1 |  |  |
| 1.2 | Subj2- | Tname1 |  |  |

**table_students:**

| student | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stname1 | -- | -- |
| stname2 | -- | -- |
| stname3 | -- | -- |
| stname4 | -- | -- |
| (x-amount of stname) | -- | -- |

#### table_stpresents:

This is an *attendance record* and will have 1 row for each student and each day. If the student is present at the start of the day, then they are expected to have attended each of their scheduled classes for that day.

| student | Date | present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stname1 | Date1 | - yes - |
| stname2 | Date1 | - no - |
| x amount of stname | Date1 | -yes- |
| stname1 | Date2 | -no- |
| stname2 | Date2 | -yes- |
| x amount of stname | Date2 | -yes- |

#### table_timetable:

Student names are referenced here as a comma delimited string (CSV) value, there is 1 row for each timetabled class in each day

| date | subj1 | subj2 | subj3 | stnames |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date1 | Subj1- | Subj3- | Subj2- | stname1, stname2, stname5 |
| DateX | Subj3- | Subj2- | Subj1- | stname1, stname4, stname3, stname5 |

#### The expected Result:

Show 1 row for each subject that has one column for each student and that contains the `LDUS`, the Latest Date when the subject has been taught to this student, based on the days when the student was present and the timetable records that correspond to that student.

The table columns-count change by choosing a different subject group (this table will be part of a custom UI)

> **Note:** my code is able to dynamically generate the sql code, so there is no need for a *dynamic* SQL solution.

| teach-id | teach | teacher | stname1 | stname2 | ..... | stnameX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | Subj1- | Tname1 | -LDUS- | -LDUS- | -LDUS- |  |
| 1.2 | Subj2- | Tname2 | -LDUS- | -LDUS- | -LDUS- |  |

### Update

I have prepared a fiddle with some example data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4bf2542240eaa86e4f4624c1e376215a

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also specify the number of columns in the result set.

Comment: You would never use a `SELECT *` in a production facing application though would you... Next time please respond to comments by editing your post.

Comment: If each column needs to represent a student, then for different classes there would be potentially a variable number of columns. If you need a variable column solution, then we need to use dynamic SQL, which is a whole new ball game, if the number of columns is fixed, or your code can dynamically generate the SQL then we can present a much simpler solution

Comment: Thanks for the verry quick responses!! My code is able to dynamically generate SQL

Comment: I won't lie, this is a horrible schema to do this type of query. Do we assume that there is only ever 1 teacher for each subject? or is `subj` unique for each teacher? usually the timetable would have `teach-id` as the unique link back to the teacher... I wouldn't use PIVOT at all for this, it would over-complicate your query, instead lets use a CASE statement

Comment: okay, i have never used a case statement

Comment: and yes there is only one teacher for each subject

Answer (score 1):

First task is to join all these tables together properly and to normalize the data. Then you can ask how to *pivot* the rows after you make sure the source data is correct.

> The source data is complicated by two structural issues:
>
> 1. Subjects in the `table_timetable` table are listed across multiple columns. To *normalise* this data we can query the table 1 time for each of the subject columns and union the results together
> 2. Students in the `table_timetable` table are stored as a CSV string value, MariaDB doesn't have a built-in function to query this type of data, but we can use a CTE to split out the names into individual rows, this is explored in this SO question: [SQL (Maria DB) split string separated by comma to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64454071/1690217)

For everyone at home, if you have a similar requirement without these two complications, then this simplified fiddle might help: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9dfce7084321699d1262bb50ca724d9e

The following query will normalize the recordset:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select `Date`,subj1,subj2,subj3,'            ' as stname, concat(stnames, ',') as stnames, 1 as lev
      from table_timetable
      union all
      select `Date`,subj1,subj2,subj3,substring_index(stnames, ',', 1),
             substr(stnames, instr(stnames, ',') + 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where stnames like '%,%'
     )
, bySubject as (
select `Date`,subj1 as subj, stname
from cte
where lev > 1
union all
select `Date`,subj2 as subj, stname
from cte
where lev > 1
union all
select `Date`,subj3 as subj, stname
from cte
where lev > 1
)
select `Date`,subj,stname
from bySubject
```

For my test DB this comes out to:

|Date       |subj   |stname |
|-----------|-------|-------|
|2021-08-16 |Subj1- |stname1|
|2021-08-16 |Subj1- |stname1|
|2021-08-16 |Subj1- |stname2|
|2021-08-17 |Subj2- |stname1|
|2021-08-17 |Subj2- |stname2|
|2021-08-17 |Subj1- |stname2|
|2021-08-18 |Subj1- |stname1|
|2021-08-18 |Subj4- |stname2|
|2021-08-18 |Subj3- |stname1|
|2021-08-19 |Subj1- |stname1|
...

See the fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f31cab287fdd575054e3af457a9cf14d

Finally to PIVOT this data into columns for each student... this is where MariaDB really lets us down, there is no in-built support for PIVOT, you have to manually construct the result yourself. You could use more CTEs but if your application is able to construct the SQL, a simpler query is to simply use a `CASE` statement to construct each column:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select `Date`,subj1,subj2,subj3,'            ' as stname, concat(stnames, ',') as stnames, 1 as lev
      from table_timetable
      union all
      select `Date`,subj1,subj2,subj3,substring_index(stnames, ',', 1),
             substr(stnames, instr(stnames, ',') + 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where stnames like '%,%'
     )
, bySubject as (
select `Date`,subj1 as subj, stname
from cte
where lev > 1
union all
select `Date`,subj2 as subj, stname
from cte
where lev > 1
union all
select `Date`,subj3 as subj, stname
from cte
where lev > 1
)
select teacher.`teach-id`, teach, teacher
    , MAX(CASE WHEN stname = 'stname1' THEN attendance.Date END) AS stname1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN stname = 'stname2' THEN attendance.Date END) AS stname2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN stname = 'stname3' THEN attendance.Date END) AS stname3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN stname = 'stname4' THEN attendance.Date END) AS stname4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN stname = 'stname5' THEN attendance.Date END) AS stname5
FROM bySubject tt
/*INNER JOIN table_students s ON tt.stname = s.student*/
INNER JOIN table_stpresents attendance ON tt.Date = attendance.Date AND tt.stname = attendance.student
INNER JOIN table_toteach teacher ON tt.subj = teacher.teach
WHERE attendance.present = '- yes -'
GROUP BY teacher.`teach-id`, teach, teacher
ORDER BY `teach-id`;
```

> **NOTE:** I commented out the join on `table_student` because you do not need any information from that table, in fact it would be hard to include it in this output, you are best to leave that to your application logic if you need is to resolve the column names.
> You might use the join to add filter criteria, so I leave it there for you to explore.

This results in:

| teach-id | teach | teacher | stname1 | stname2 | stname3 | stname4 | stname5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | Subj1- | Tname1 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-18 |
| 1.2 | Subj2- | Tname2 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-18 |
| 1.5 | Subj3- | Tname3 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-16 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-18 |
| 2.0 | Subj4- | Tname4 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-19 |  | 2021-08-18 |

This is a simpler form of `PIVOT` to maintain if you are generating the query in your code, notice that you just need to repeat the max statement for each student column.

This final solution is in the following db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f07c943d3d92ea0de8d91021728ab7c0

For alternate methods see [Pivoting in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pivoting-in-mariadb/)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for trying things out but i stated the time table wrong my bad!! The time table has a colum named Students, and there are many Students in 1 field. And the time table uses 3 Subjects (3 Columns) for each row, im sorry let me get things straight

SORRY FOR MISPUTTING THE PROBLEM AND THANKS !!
time table:
tech1 tech2 tech3  teacher  stnames                          date
Subj1 SubjX SubjY  Tname1  nameX, nameY, nameZ  2021-08-18  
Subj2 SubjX SubjY  Tname1  nameX, nameY, nameZ   2021-08-18

i will respond in 2 hours when im at home thanks a lot

Comment: This answer matches your post and as it stands will benefit the community. Please make a new post including the schema, perhaps you can create a fiddle like I did with an example dataset that matches your actual runtime. Omit the Collins that are not relevant. Link to this and I'll provide a tailored answer. You have to do some of the work ;)

Comment: so i did the tables in fiddle how they actually are:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4bf2542240eaa86e4f4624c1e376215a

Comment: Does `table_timetable` really have multiple columns for subjects?