# Retrieving min value in json array from MariaDB table

Tags: sql, json, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I have a MariaDB table including a JSON field:

```
{
    arrayOfDates : ['2020-01-11', '2021-01, 12', '2019-03-12'],
    ...
}
```

For each record in `my-table` I need to extract the field arrayOfDates and pick the min value in the array.

Note I'm using MariaDB v 10.5.x so I cannot use JSON_TABLE.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is like this:

```
create table tbl (jsn text);
insert into tbl (jsn) values 
  ('{"arrayOfDates":["2020-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2019-03-12"],"other":[0,1]}');
```

You can use a recursive CTE to "loop" through the JSON array and extract every single date.

```
with recursive rcte (seq, jsn, dt) as (
  select 0, jsn, json_extract(jsn, '$.arrayOfDates[0]')
  from tbl
  union all
  select seq + 1, jsn, json_extract(jsn, replace('$.arrayOfDates[?]', '?', seq+1))
  from rcte
  where json_extract(jsn, replace('$.arrayOfDates[?]', '?', seq+1)) is not null
)
select * from rcte
```

| seq | jsn | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | {"arrayOfDates":["2020-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2019-03-12"],"other":[0,1]} | "2020-01-11" |
| 1 | {"arrayOfDates":["2020-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2019-03-12"],"other":[0,1]} | "2021-01-12" |
| 2 | {"arrayOfDates":["2020-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2019-03-12"],"other":[0,1]} | "2019-03-12" |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2yMRZgEJ)

This query is based on a recursive sequence query.
It starts from the first array element (at index/position `0`)
and *loops* "recursively" through the sequence numbers and the according array elements.
Our recusion stop condition is the absence of an array element
at the position of the sequence number (`where json_extract([..] seq+1)) is not null`).
A single date is extracted with the [JSON_EXTRACT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/) function.
The sequence number ('seq+1') is "injected" into the JSON path
using the [REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replace-function/) function.

In the outer query you can now select `MIN`, `MAX` or what ever you want from the above result.

```
create table tbl (jsn text);
insert into tbl (jsn) values 
  ('{"arrayOfDates":["2020-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2019-03-12"],"other":[0,1]}');
```

```
with recursive rcte (seq, jsn, dt) as (
  [..]
)
select jsn, min(dt) as min_dt
from rcte
group by jsn
```

| jsn | min_dt |
| --- | --- |
| {"arrayOfDates":["2020-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2019-03-12"],"other":[0,1]} | "2019-03-12" |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G1oHwFzh)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select '            ' as dt, REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(myjson, '$.arrayOfDates'), '[', ''), ']', ',') as dates, 1 as lev
      from mytable
      union all
      select substring_index(dates, ',', 1),
             substr(dates, instr(dates, ',') + 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where dates like '%,%'
)
select MAX(dt) AS max_date
from cte
where lev > 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TxcB8UDq)

see :

- [SQL (Maria DB) split string separated by comma to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64454134/4286884)

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB 10.5, if you cannot use JSON_TABLE,
However, you can use the combination of JSON functions and regular SQL. Here's an example query to get the minimum value from the arrayOfDates field for each record:

```
    SELECT 
        your_table.*, 
        (SELECT MIN(CAST(date AS DATE)) 
         FROM JSON_TABLE(your_table.json_column, '$.arrayOfDates[*]' 
         COLUMNS (date CHAR(10) PATH '$'))) AS min_date
    FROM 
        your_table;
```

Replace `your_table` with the actual name of your table and `json_column` with the name of your JSON column.

This query uses a subquery to extract the `arrayOfDates` from the JSON column using `JSON_TABLE`. It then uses the `MIN` function to find the minimum value after casting the dates to the `DATE` type.